# Update List Item in Form

Tags: list, infopath, form, item

I have a list of Computer Names containing different columns, like Name, Description, and Price.

e.g.

MacBook Pro / Intel i7 / $2300

I have a form made with InfoPath where I have a dropdown that points the title of the computer, and then I have some rules that get triggered when a specific computer title is selected. For example, if in the dropdown I select MacBook Pro, I have a rule that will display the price and description (added manually).

Is there any way where I can point the description and price to a field within the form so I don't have to do it manually?

Sometimes we may have to add new computers to the list and adding it manually can be a little bit annoying.

Thank you beforehand for your help.

Comment: You mean currently you hard coded the value for each of the computer on the form itself?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you wish to display the description and price for similar types of computers by default, as you did with the Mac Book.

What you can do is create some sets of fields - description and price. Next, when a particular type of computer is selected, you display only that particular computer's details (say Mac's price and description) and hide all all the other's details. Similarly, when you change the computer type, it will hide the previous description and display the current computer's value (let's say a Windows computer and it's related description and price).

Ofcourse you'll have to manually add the price and description for each type of computer.

However, this can be made dynamic also if you store the details in a separate list and query the corresponding details on the drop down change of the computer. A simple data query should suffice.

Hope I answered your query!